# Lifting morphisms between fundamental groupoids

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

The fundamental groupoid functor $\Pi : \mathbf{Top} \rightarrow \mathbf{Gpd}$ is not full. However, I am interested in special cases where it is always possible to lift a morphism (functor) between fundamental groupoids to a continuous map between spaces.

In particular, is it the case that we can always lift endomorphisms $\Pi(X) \rightarrow \Pi(X)$ to continuous maps $X \rightarrow X$? If not in general, then what about for path spaces: can we lift endomorphisms $\Pi(X^I) \rightarrow \Pi(X^I)$ to continuous maps $X^I \rightarrow X^I$?

If a universal (in some sense) choice of liftings can be made, that would be cool, but I'm satisfied with simply the existence of a continuous function that maps via $\Pi$ back down to the functor in question.

Comment: I think something like this is true: if $X$ is a 1-truncated CW-complex and $Y$ is any topological space, then every functor $\Pi (X) \to \Pi (Y)$ comes from some continuous map $X \to Y$ (up to isomorphism in the category of functors $\Pi (X) \to \Pi (Y)$).

Comment: I don't know much about groupoids, but I do know that for lens spaces $L_p$ with $\pi_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, most isomorphisms of $\pi_1$ are not induced by self maps.  In fact, the only isomorphisms obtained via continuous maps are $\pm Id_{\pi_1}$.  Does that help with the groupoid case?

Comment: @Jason: up to some futzing around about whether the OP wants a lift up to equivalence or (for whatever reason) wants a lift on the nose (in which case the answer could depend *a priori* on which choice of basepoints is being used for the fundamental groupoid)), for path-connected spaces you can safely reduce to thinking about fundamental groups.

Comment: Thanks @JasonDeVito and QiaochuYuan. That rules out lifting arbitrary endomorphisms (up to iso is fine).

Comment: Thanks @ZhenLin. Does it follow somehow from your observation that we can lift endomorphisms on fundamental groupoids of path spaces (up to iso)? I mean, an endofunctor on $\Pi(X^I)$ in particular assigns maps $I \rightarrow X$ to maps $I \rightarrow X$. Perhaps functoriality implies continuity of this assignment (or existence of a homotopic assignment)?

Comment: I made a mistake in the above comment.  For such lens spaces, most isomorphisms of $\pi_1$ are not induced by diffeomorphisms, but I'm not sure about arbitrary continuous maps.

Comment: @ssp8 Well, the problem is invariant under homotopy equivalence, and the inclusion of constant paths $X \to X^I$ is a homotopy equivalence, so I don't think it's an issue that $X^I$ itself is not usually a CW-complex.

Comment: I see. I think I'm getting a bit more of a handle on your first observation. Asking that endofunctors on fundamental groupoids lift to continuous maps (up to homotopy) is like asking that functors between homotopy categories (groupoids) lift to infinity-functors between infinity-groupoids, which in general only seems possible if the domain is secretly a 1-category, right?

Comment: By the way, according to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/166153/realizing-homomorphisms-between-fundamental-groups?rq=1 , all maps $\pi_1(L_p)\rightarrow \pi_1(L_p)$ are induced by continuous maps $L_p\rightarrow L_p$.  This follows since $\pi_2(L_p) = 0$ (being covered by $S^3$) and $H^k(L_p; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for $k\geq 4$.